# Javascript avoid audio repetition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been triying to avoid audio repetition using JAVASCRIPT.
My ANGULARJS code,

```
var feeling1 = $('#feeling1');
$(feeling1)[0].addEventListener('ended', function() {
 this.currentTime = 0;
 this.play();
 this.loop();
}, false);
var feeling1_timer;
var breath1 = $('#breath1');
$(breath1)[0].addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
  this.loop();
}, false);
var breath1_timer;
```

My ANGULARJS functions are,

```
$scope.playguided = function(session){
  var time = (2*60 + 30) * 1000
  feeling1_timer = $timeout(function(){ $scope.callAtTimeout(2.30); }, time);
  time = (3*60 + 30) * 1000
  breath1_timer = $timeout(function(){ $scope.callAtTimeout(3.30); }, time);
}

$scope.callAtTimeout = function(interval){
 if(interval == 2.30){
    $(feeling1)[0].play();
 }else if(interval == 3.30){
   $(feeling1)[0].pause();
   $(breath1)[0].play();
 }
}

$scope.stopguidedmusic = function(){
 $(feeling1)[0].pause();
 $timeout.cancel(feeling1_timer);
 $(breath1)[0].pause();
 $timeout.cancel(breath1_timer);
}
```

My 'feeling1' music file's length is 1 mins. But it keeps repeating upto 3:30 mins. I don't want repetition.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you want the "feeling1" play just once 
OR are you trying to implement looping a sample for a certain time and then stop?
So, the sentence "My 'feeling1' music file's length is 1 mins. But it keeps repeating upto 3:30 mins. I don't want repetition."  refers to the first scenario, but then I'm confused why inside ``ended`` handler you call ``this.play();this.loop();`` which causes the sample to loop.

Comment: I want this play just once. @tiblu

Comment: Then don't call ``this.play(); this.loop();`` inside ``ended`` handler?

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.. Actually, I am new to javascript and angularjs. @tiblu